# ASP.net Cloud services

Tags: .net, cloud

I have tried Microsoft Azure, they have the best and easiest deployment tools for .Net platform as well as some other technologies like node.js, PHP, and Ruby.

The only down side is the trial period, it is only 90 days. I never converted to paid customer.

I am looking for something like Google App Engine, which let you use for free as long as you never hit above the free quota. It is very useful for developer to really test the platform before commmit to pay.

Any other cloud services for .Net, which does not have specific trial limitation?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, questions about free hosting are off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill I am not talking about free hosting, I am looking for pay cloud hosting, but longer trial period.

Comment: Questions about pay cloud hosting services are also off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) has an unlimited free plan. (I'm a co-founder)